# Outputting a specific line from a list in a file and converting it into a string

Tags: python, string, list

I am stuck on a task of where I have to output n-th line from a file and I need it outputted as a string.

```
file = open("/usercode/files/pull_ups.txt")
n = int(input())
print(file.readlines(n))
file.close()`enter code here
```

This outputs '['Day 0, 8 pull ups\n']' and  I need it to output Day 1, 8 pull ups

Comment: `file.readlines(n)` will read first n bytes, not first n lines. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readlines.asp

Comment: use: eval(input_str)[0]. this should work.

Comment: @PiyushSambhi there is literally zero reason to use `eval` in this case. Just go through the first n-1 lines and output the next one.

Comment: Understood about the displaying bytes hence why it showed day 0. How would I go about displaying n-th day? Not too sure which function to use for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt") as file: # cleaner way of opening a file
   n = int(input())
   for i in range(n-1):        # skip first n-1 lines of a file
      file.readline()
   print(file.readline())      # read n-th line
```